# Using schemas in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I am using Django 1.8..

I have been trying to make migrations of a specific app of which models have prefixes describing the schema they belong to. So here is an example:

```
class NetworkFeature(models.Model):
    id_network_feature = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'"schema1"."network_feature"'

class ComplexElement(NetworkFeature):
    complex_element_class = models.ForeignKey(ComplexElementClass, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'"schema1"."complex_element"'
```

I have played around with the 
'schema"."table'
'schema\".\"table'
and all the possible combinations and nothing seems really to solve the problem, when I do `makemigrations <my-app>` it works fine but when I run `migrate <my-app>`, it's been showing up..

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: zero-length delimited identifier at
>   or near """"
>       LINE 1: CREATE INDEX ""schema1"."network_feature"_2b331646" ON "schema1"."ne...

or

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "." LINE 1:
>   CREATE INDEX "schema1"."complex_element_58db0be5" ON ...

If I try to change my settings.py's search-path, it doesn't find the foreign keys..

There were some other threads talking about it, but none of them have a replicable answer and/or aren't for 1.8 that is an LTS. It appears to me that there isn't a way to perform that out of the box..

Comment: Remove the quotes. `db_table = u'schema1.network_feature'`

Comment: Hi Daniel, it actually adds a table called schema1.network_feature in my public schema.. like http://imgur.com/a/00V1i